# GIMP: Actions search?

Tags: shortcuts, gimp

Is there a "actions search" or "shortcuts search" functionality in GIMP?

For example, I want "rotate", but I don't remember where it is in the menu. I'd be happy to type in "rotate" or "rot" and see available actions and their shortcuts. Is it possible in GIMP?

// This thing is also sometimes called "shortcut of shortcuts". Because you remember one shortcut -- how to start searching -- and all other actions can follow from that.

Comment: I think [the answer of @Honghe.Wu](https://superuser.com/a/1325904/191663) answers your question. If so, could you mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: @kdb hey, that's an interesting question. I prefer to not place an accepted mark on StackExchange-based services because it pins the answer on top. I find that a lot of those pins get outdated quickly, if the author is no longer to verify the new answers. I did upvote both current answers, however, as I found both of them useful

Comment: @kdb In other words, I find the feature of pinning answers more distracting than useful in other's peoples answers, so I never use it myself. I carefully always do upvotes whenever an answer helps me though

Comment: @kdb I tried to google if other people feel the same, and indeed found it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095/please-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top

Answer (score 4):

Use `/` to search command/action and run it.

Reference
https://wiki.gimp.org/index.php/Specs:Action_Search_Dialog

Answer (score 3):

See *Edit>Keyboard shortcuts* and type in part of what you are looking for in the filter field at the top (this of course also allows you to change the shortcuts)

[image]

Comment: Super-cool, thanks! EDIT: though it works only half-way through. I can see the actions, but I can't launch them. Do you by chance also know how to launch a command by name?

Comment: You cannot uses these commands. Some of them have nearly direct equivalents in the functions used by scripts but on the whole these are UI functions. You can always achieve the same results by other means (for instance there is a slider to rotate the brush) if you don't assign them to keys or mouse actions. For scripts, both the script-fu and python-fu consoles have a "Browse" button that lets you search functions by name.